# need a jquery code:

Tags: jquery, html

suppose i have 3 text fields and 3 buttons
so what i want is i click on any one text field and when i click on a button the value stored in the button goes to the text field i have previously clicked here is the code what i have tried.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>


    <body><button class="b"></button>
    <button class="a">abc</button>
    <button class="a">def</button>
    <button class="a">ghi</button>

    <div class="fill" id="f1"><input type="text" value=""> aaaa</div>
    <div class="fill" id="f2"><input type="text" >bbbb</div>
    <div class="fill" id="f3"><input type="text" >ccc</div>


    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

 $('.fill').each(function(index, element) {
             $(this).click(function(){
                var temp = $(this).attr('id');
                $('.b').click(function(){
                    alert($('.b').val())

                $('.a').each(function(){
                    $(this).click(function(){
                    $('.fill').val()=$(temp).val()
                    });
                });
             });
 });})

</script>
</body>
```

'

Comment: Not clear with 'i click on any one text field and when i click on a button the value ...' this sentence, can you please elaborate more by taking an example of shared html?

Comment: I understood what you mean, I had to read it a hundred time :)

Comment: This JS code is a mess :)

Comment: **Why would you ever** want to click first on a field and that on a button? Why not click directly the button?

Comment: also what's the button `.b` for?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need this piece of javascript:

```
var activeInput = undefined;

$('.fill input').on('click', function() {
    activeInput = this;
});

$('.a').on('click', function() {
    if(!activeInput) return;
    $(activeInput).val($(this).text());
    // optional:
    // activeInput = undefined;
});
```

What it does: you hit an input, and it saves which input you have clicked in the `activeInput` var. Then when you hit a button, it passes it's value (or the text value that is) to the input field. You can optionally reset the activeInput var again if you don't want users to continiously hit other buttons.

**[JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/tj00rwh2/)**

Comment: +1 for understanding the problem statement correctly and proving correct answer :), I did not understand it :(

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
var activeFill;

$('.fill input').on('click',function() {
   activeFill = $(this); 
});

$('button').on('click',function() {
    if (activeFill !== 'undefined') {
       var val = $(this).html();
       $(activeFill).val(val);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="b"></button>
<button class="a">abc</button>
<button class="a">def</button>
<button class="a">ghi</button>

<div class="fill" id="f1"><input type="text" value=""> aaaa</div>
<div class="fill" id="f2"><input type="text" >bbbb</div>
<div class="fill" id="f3"><input type="text" >ccc</div>
```

Comment: You `if (activeFill !== 'undefined') {` fails only for the first time until you click on any of the text and after clicking any text first time it will never fail.

Comment: That's the idea. If it's undefined don't bother running the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote a working example:

```
$('button.a').mousedown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = $('input:focus');
    if (input.length == 1) {
        input.val($(this).text()).focus();
    }
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hL4e0s67/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use each. .click() method is added to each one of the set. so
`$('.fill').click()` 
is the same as

```
 $('.fill').each(function() {
     $(this).click()
 });
```

This being said, keep it simple

```
/* store the previous clicked input text */
var previous = null;    
$('.fill input').click(function() {
    previous = this;
});

/* change text on button click */
$('.a').click(function() {
    if (previous == null)
        return;
    $(previous).text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Yeah it's a shame preview doesn't show code colors ;) Corrected